# Xcode C code, "division by zero" analyzer issue

Tags: c, xcode, clang, static-analysis

I have a C file that includes the following snippet of code inside a function:

```
assert( pCache->nHash>0 && pCache->apHash );
...
if( pPage ){
    unsigned int h = iKey % pCache->nHash; 
...
```

When I run Analyze, Xcode throws a Logic Error - Division by Zero, on the last line containing the modulus operation.

If I add an extra check to the if like so, the error goes away:

```
if( pPage && pCache->nHash>0 ){
```

Shouldn't the assert containing `pCache->nHash>0` avoid divisions by zero, which in turn ?

Comment: Is there any way that value can change during the `...` in your code snippet? It might just be a false positive from the analyzer - those happen pretty often.

Comment: I considered that, so I changed the assert to the line above the error and it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assertions are most often used during development only. When you build the final release, you disable assertions.

With that said, assertions are there to capture logic errors that should be corrected/checked by the developer. They aren't used as actual validation for the logic of your program.

This explains why you must still add an if statement checking if your variable is greater than 0. Your analyzer analyzes your code and most likely ignores asserts, since you are expected to remove them during the final build.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @Cubia. Am I expected to actually remove them during the final build, or will my device ignore any assert calls by itself? Just as a side-note, in my case this is a library that people would add to their projects via source, or CocoaPods.

Comment: @heitortsergent You aren't necessarily expected to remove them during the final build. But asserts are supposed to be used in the development cycle only. Your device wont ignore assertions, but if ever an assertion fails, one would expect that assertion to be replaced by an actual check (if statement, etc...). Also, there is usually a performance penalty when using assertions, so remove them does improve your programs performance.